# Event which triggers if an Exception was thrown

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to create something like an event in java which will be triggered if an Exception was thrown?

I want to make something like a exception tracking system which sends all Exception to a central server.

Is this possible or do I have to call a method on myself within every catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to handle this would be with logging (for example SLF4J and Logback). You can configure loggers to send the messages to a centralized logging server, but you still need to manually log the exception and if applicable, handle it.

If you were hoping for an automagical way to just forget about exceptions, that's not really possible. Exception handling is not as easy as it may seem, if you intend to make your applications robust and easily debuggable.

A good additional "trick" is to use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to provide a final fail-safe. Its only job should be to log any exceptions that aren't handled elsewhere. However it should happen only in case there's a massive failure and the stacktrace might otherwise be lost. If it's being invoked just because some input was of the wrong format, your design and code is of poor quality.

Comment: So there is no possibility to get exceptions which are not thrown by my own methods but by an API or java itself?

Comment: @Ybrin Of course. You can catch them just like any exceptions, there's no need for anything special whether you're throwing an exception or Java/3rd party API is throwing an exception

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for.